# how to go fullScreen "MediaView" in javaFX / FXML?

Tags: javafx, media-player, fxml, fxmlloader

I have a problem of full screen for the media View, I made my interface with scene builder and when I implement the method of fullScreen all the window becomes in full screen mode and not the mediaView only.

```
 private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer; 

@FXML
private MediaView mediaView;

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private String filepath;

@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {

}



@FXML
private void openFile(ActionEvent event){
    FileChooser fileChooser=new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter filter =new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("select a file","*.mp4","*.mp3");
    fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().add(filter);

    File file=fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    filepath = file.toURI().toString();


    if(filepath!=null){
    Media media = new Media(filepath);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

    mediaPlayer.play();


}
}
@FXML
private void fullScreen(ActionEvent event){



    ((Stage)mediaView.getScene().getWindow()).setFullScreen(true);



}
```

Comment: "[...]all the window becomes in full screen mode and not the mediaView only" : it is actually what you coded with this line of code : `((Stage)mediaView.getScene().getWindow()).setFullScreen(true);` You retrieve the stage, and make it fullscreen. One idea could be to set the `MediaView` as root of your `Scene`.

Comment: How ? I created another Stage but that's not what I want :( I do not know how to add the MediaView as root of my Screen.


@FXML
private void fullScreen(ActionEvent event){
Stage primaryStage = new Stage();       mediaView.setPreserveRatio(true);
 StackPane root = new StackPane();
 root.getChildren().add(mediaView);
Scene scene=new Scene(root);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
primaryStage.show();
 }